# How do you use a custom view in a HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: java, android, xml, overloading, android-imageview

I've got a custom view (called `CustomStrechView`) which `extends` an `ImageView`. The point of this view is so that I can get an image to fill the view without losing the aspect ratio.

Now the `CustomStrechView` works fine when I use it in most applications, but when I try to apply it within my `HorizontalScrollView`, the images all seem to disappear. I'm not sure why this happens. I've tried removing the `<HorizontalScrollView />` and when I do the images show back up, so I feel there is some property that needs to be set, but I can't seem to find it.

Can anyone point out what I’m doing wrong or a better way to get a custom view to work in a `HorizontalScrollView`?

---

*Edit*:

After playing around with this for a bit, I've determined that I can get the custom view to show the image only if I hardcode the `width` dimension, ie:

```
<com.example.dragdropshapes.CustomStrechView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
```

Leaving the height as `fill_parent` is fine...

---

*Code*:

Here's how my custom view is being used in the xml file:

```
<!-- Removing this makes the images show up -->
<HorizontalScrollView       
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!-- Changing this to a normal ImageView makes the image show up -->
        <com.example.dragdropshapes.CustomStrechView
            android:id="@+id/pickshapes"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="pickShapes"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
        <!-- There are 5 other custom ImageViews here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here's the major part of the custom view code:

```
public class CustomStrechView extends ImageView{

  private final Drawable srcPic;
  private final String TAG = "strechyTag";
  private boolean changeSize = false;
  private int Xpx;
  private int Ypx;

    public CustomStrechView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        srcPic = this.getDrawable();
    }

     //... other constructors, not really important...

     protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
         Log.d(TAG, "in the onMeasure!!\n");
         int width, height;

        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = width * srcPic.getIntrinsicHeight() / srcPic.getIntrinsicWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting ??

Comment: @Hussain - I'm not getting an "error", just no image appears. The `HorizontalScrollView` shows nothing. The splash screen loads as normal and moves the the scroll view, if I use `ImageView`s then I see the pictures (but poorly sized) if I swap it for my custom view then nothing appears at all

Answer (score 0):

Through some debugging I was able to at least partially solve this myself. Turns out that the `width` acquired from the `MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);` call was 0. Thus the calculation ended in width and height being 0 and the `setMeasuredDimension` call would then make the image invisible.

Now I'm saying I have this *partially* solved, because I still don't understand *why* I was getting that value of 0. I ***think*** it's because in a `HorizontalScrollView` the width isn't determined (it depends on the content within) thus whatever `MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);` is actually doing is talking to the parent, and the parent in a normal `Linear` or `RelativeLayout` has a defined width where as in a `HorizontalScrollView` it does not... but that's just speculation at this point.

So I made a fix for it, if the `width` is 0 we run the calculation via the `height` instead. The `height` needed two cases to cover it to avoid divide by 0 errors (the `else if` and the `else` collectively).

Here's my current solution with the same xml file I noted in the Question.

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if(width > 0)
        height = width * srcPic.getIntrinsicHeight() / srcPic.getIntrinsicWidth();
    else if(srcPic.getIntrinsicWidth() < srcPic.getIntrinsicHeight())
     width = height / (srcPic.getIntrinsicHeight() / srcPic.getIntrinsicWidth());
    else
     width = height / (srcPic.getIntrinsicWidth() / srcPic.getIntrinsicHeight());

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```